# Use of jhipster application in microservices

Tags: jhipster

first of all I am new to Jhipster. I have created jhipster gateway (Frontend) with angular without application (backend).

I was expecting that this will not work as backend is not present/working and all service calls will go through backend to access db.

When I am trying to access frontend using http://localhost:8080, I can see everthing is working. I am not sure how.  can someone explain?

JHipster v6.10.5 is used for this.

Thanks
Shirish

Application responses for JHispter commandline:

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Microservice gateway 
? [Beta] Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? No 
? What is the base name of your application? gateway 
? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8080 
? What is your default Java package name? com.btn.test 
? Which service discovery server do you want to use? JHipster Registry (uses Eureka, provides Spring Cloud Config support and monitoring dashboards) 
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token) 
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL) 
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL ? Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL 
? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? Yes, with the Hazelcast implementation (distributed cache, for multiple nodes, supports rate-limiting for gateway applications) 
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes 
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven 
? Which other technologies would you like to use? 
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular 
? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Default JHipster 
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No 
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Gatling, Cucumber, Protractor 
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? (y/N) No
```

---

### emp.jdl

```
/**
 * The Employee entity.
 * @author Shirish Bathe
 */
entity Employee {
    name String required unique
    dept String
}
```

Now I have access gateway using http://localhost:8080 and tried to access employee entity. I am able to see (fake) data in a table.

Hence Even if backend application is not present, application is working fine.  how? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The gateway contains the whole UI. The microservices come into play when you define entities. These are not managed by the gateway (but the UI is). This overview pictures describes the architecture quite well:

https://www.jhipster.tech/microservices-architecture/

Comment: thanks for swift response. I have created gateway application using below inputs and added new entity using jdl (emp.jdl). Now I have access gateway using http://localhost:8080 and tried to access employee entity. I am able to see (fake) data in a table.

Hence Even if backend application is not present, application is working fine.  how? Am I missing anything? 
You can access sample code @ https://github.com/bathe/test. I am using mysql db with root as user is and password.

Comment: Can you post your jdl? You can define where the entites are created. It is event possible to have entities on the gateway. Looking at your code, the employee entity is part of the gateway. See here for example https://github.com/bathe/test/blob/main/src/main/java/com/btn/test/web/rest/EmployeeResource.java. The data you see is created via liquibase migration when running in dev profile.

Comment: My Jdl is simple and posted as a part of my main question. I have generated gateway using jhipster command and then I have added emp entity  using above jdl.  Can you please let me know how to define where are created.  I want all entities in application(backend) code.

Comment: Have a look at this example. You define three applications (1 gateway, 2 microservices). Each application contains the entities they are responsible for. https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/main/reactive-ms.jdl You can do jhipster jdl in an empty directory and it will create three folders (gateway, blog microservice and store microservice) for you.